# Obtener valores de select option con jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tengo que crear tablas de actividades por día, es decir, según las fechas que obtenga de la base de datos mando a mostrar las tablas...

Por ejemplo, si obtengo 2 fechas de la BD, creo y muestro 2 tablas que deben ser independientes en su contenido, estas tablas ya las muestro, el nombre de la actividad he logrado hacerlo independiente, pero no sé cómo obtener los valores del select option, que son la hora de inicio y la hora fin de cada actividad.

Este es mi código de jQuery:

```
function ii(){
 var a = $("#evento_hora_ii option:selected" ).text();
 $('#evento_hora_ii').each(function() {
 a = $("#evento_hora_ii option:selected" ).text();
 })
 return a;
}

function ff(){
 var b = $("#evento_hora_ff option:selected" ).text();
 $('#evento_hora_ff').each(function() {
 b = $("#evento_hora_ff option:selected" ).text();
 })
 return b;
}

$(document).on("click","#add",function(){

 var fecha = $(this).data("fecha");

 $('#mytable .actividad').each(function(){
 if($(this).html() != ""){
  var actividad = $(this).html();

  var aa = ii();
  var bb = ff();

  $.ajax({
   url: "tabla_funciones/insertar.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: {actividad:actividad, hr_inicio:aa, hr_fin:bb, fecha:fecha},
   error: function() {
   alert("Error");
  },
  success: function(data){
  obtener_datos();
  }
 })
}
else{}
}) 
});
```

En las funciones ii() y ff() trato de obtener la hora inicio y fin, pero únicamente obtengo las horas de la primera tabla, para la segunda tabla sólo obtengo espacios en blanco.

¿Qué estaré haciendo mal?

Comment: Pienso que deberías probar append en vez de igualar la variable, es posible que existan elementos ocultos en esa tabla que solo lo añade como valor vacio, entonces cada vez que recorres con el each no añadas ningún elemento a la variable. Intenta colocar b.append($("#evento_hora_ff option:selected" ).text());

Comment: @harifo gracias por tu respuesta, pero la línea de código que propones no funciona...

Comment: Si se trata de llenar elementos `select`, entonces tendrías que agregar correctamente los diferentes `option` y luego colocarlos en el `select` respectivo (usando preferiblemente su `id` para alcanzarlos). Dicho eso, no entiendo mucho la lógica de tu código, por ejemplo, ¿qué sentido tienen los `return` en las funciones `ii()` y `ff()`? ¿Por qué mejor no llenas los elementos allí dentro sin más? Otra pregunta fundamental: ¿has depurado los datos, vara verificar si están llegando realmente desde el servidor?

Comment: @A.Cedano la cuestión aquí es que precisamente no estoy obteniendo los valores del option de la segunda tabla. Cabe mencionar que el primer option es disabled selected con este contenido '--------'.
Los valores seleccionados de la primera tabla llegan correctamente, pero de la segunda me devuelve: '--------'.

Comment: Entiendo, por eso he hablado de **depurar**. ¿De dónde deben venir esos datos y qué depuraciones has hecho y con qué resultados?

Comment: @A.Cedano los datos vienen de un archivo llamado _mostrar_datos.php_, y los recibo en el archivo _completar_evento.php_ que es donde los proceso, la información de la primera tabla es bien recibida, pero de la segunda nada...

Comment: Como ya dije, tienes que depurar. ¿Dónde esperas los datos? Supongo que aquí: `success: function(data){`, pero ahí luego llamas a `obtener_datos()` y en el código ni siquiera se ve esa función. En cualquier caso, los datos que esperas estarían en `data`, debes revisarlos mediante `console.log(data);` para ver qué está viniendo del servidor. Si verificas que los datos llegan bien puedes incluso procesarlos dentro del bloque del `success`, estás, a mi juicio trabajando con un código un poco confuso sin necesidad.

Comment: @A.Cedano las funciones son únicamente un intento de solución, pero están evidentemente mal, espero tener éxito.

Comment: @A.Cedano cuando se logren obtener los datos se hace una inserción a base de datos, entro a success y llamo a la función `obtener_datos()` para "actualizar" las tablas

Comment: No logro entender la lógica que hay en tu código y creo que ahí está el problema también para ti. Sugiero que analices tu lógica, que tengas claro: quiero hacer esto de este modo, esta función para esto y esta para lo otro. Luego, si algo no funciona depuras: *esto no funciona, no muestra nada... vamos a mostrar los datos en consola a ver qué pasa, etc* No sé si me explico, en tu pregunta no hay nada de eso, la lógica no es clara ni se indica lo que se ha depurado. Así es complicado dar con el problema, que no es tan complicado sin duda, pero no hay por donde cogerlo como lo tienes planteado.

Comment: @A. Cedano tengo bastante claro lo que quiero que mi aplicación haga, simplemente estoy atorado en un procedimiento. Saludos.

Comment: ¿En cuál procedimiento? Revisando el código no logro ver exactamente dónde está el problema. Te he preguntado sobre qué has depurado y con qué resultados y tampoco lo explicas, entonces, con todo respeto, no creo que lo tengas tan claro. Mi interés es ayudar, pero si no colaboras lo veo complicado. O quizá otro usuario del sitio pueda comprender lo que ocurre y ayudarte. Desde mi punto de vista, tal y como has planteado el problema y con el código que muestras es imposible determinar dónde está el problema realmente.